pure states and characters for a commutative $C^*$-algebra
Let $A$ be the ring of continuous bounded complex-valued functions $C_b(X)$. We know that $A$ is a commutative $C^*$-algebra. Thusly the GNS representation implies an isomorphism
$$A\cong C(\hat A)$$
where $\hat A$ is the space of characters on $A$. And we know that $\hat A$ coinsides with the space of pure states of $A$. Moreover, if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then $X\cong \hat A$. But if not, what is the relation between $X$ and $\hat A$? In particular, I am interesed in the case of that $X$ is a real separable Hilbert space.

$\hat{A}$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of X, at least when X is locally compact. I am not sure if this goes beyond locally compact spaces, which is what you would need for a Hilbert space of infinite dimension

@Justdroppedin Thank you. To know that, what reference should I read?

@Justdroppedin This does work for all topological spaces $X$ (or all Tychonoff ones, if you restrict Stone-Čech compactifications to only Tychonoff spaces). In fact, this is effectively how Stone defined the Stone-Čech compactification in the first place.

There are alternative definitions of the Stone-Čech compactification, which can give you a “more concrete” description of $\hat{A}$. For example, it is the closure of $X$ in $[0, 1]^C$, where $C$ is the collection of all continuous functions $X \to [0, 1]$, and $X$ embeds in $[0, 1]^C$ by sending each $x \in X$ to its evaluation map $\text{ev}_x: C \to [0, 1]$. But ultimately every description of the Stone-Čech compactification is going to be somewhat abstract.

If $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff, then $X \subset \beta X$ ($\beta X$ is the usual notation for the Stone-Čech compactification of $X$) is open. Unfortunately that is not the case for an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, so $X \subset \beta X$ is not open in your case. If $X$ is Tychonoff, then $X \subset \beta X$ is a topological embedding, so at least that’s true in your case. More than that, $X$ in your case is completely metrizable, so it’s Čech-complete and thus $X$ is $G_\delta$ in $\beta X$. I don’t think much more can be said.

@DavidGao Thanks, David, that's useful to know.

@DavidGao Thank you for your answer!
